# Record fetching in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I want to create an Action method to fetch the information about the individual employee id from the SQL Server 2005. I want to send EmployeeID as input. I have models and separate Business Objects. Can any one help me in this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you going through the tutorials on this site: http://asp.net/mvc. There are many examples out there that will help you achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Ya I gone through taht. But I couldn't find. How can I pass the html text box which holds EmployeeID to the controller "public ActionResult Details(int id){}"

Comment: @Sivakumar, you would have a textbox in your HTML form which should be named `id`: `<input type="text" name="id" />` and when the form is submitted it will send the value to the controller.